# Visual Studio Code could not launch MATLAB

Tags: c++, matlab, visual-studio-code, mex

I want to debug my mex code with VS Code. So I am trying to setup the VS Code with my Matlab (R2018a). But VS Code could not find the path for the Matlab application. I am using the following path: `/Applications/MATLAB_R2018a.app`.

This figure shows the error message and the path used for Matlab:

[image: Images shows the error and the path used for matlab]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The MATLAB executable is at

```
/Applications/MATLAB_R2018a.app/bin/matlab
```

The path `/Applications/MATLAB_R2018a.app` is a bundle, not an executable. The MacOS UI knows what to do with it, but from a command line it just looks like a directory. I bet VS Code sees it like a directory as well.

Comment: If you right click on an app there is an option to "Show package contents". just so you know.